# How to extend a generic class with bounded typed parameter

Tags: java, generics, collections, types

I am trying to extend a Generic class with bounded typed parameter with another generic class with typed parameter which follows the super generic's typed parameter.

> Super Generic with upper bounded type parameter

```
public abstract class Cage<T extends Animal> { 
    protected Set<T> cage = new HashSet<T>();
    public abstract void add(T animal);
    public void showAnimals() {
        System.out.println(cage);
    }
}
```

Generic class I want to create with a specific bounded type e.g. Lion

I tried the below code but I am getting an error *The type parameter Lion is hiding the type Lion* and *Syntax error on token "extends", , expected*

For the add() method in LionCage class I am getting the error *The method add(Lion) of type LionCage must override or implement a supertype method*

> `LionCage` class meant for `Cage<Lion extends Animal>`

```
public class LionCage<Lion extends Animal> extends Cage<T extends Animal> {
    @Override
    public void add(Lion l) {
        cage.add(l);

    }
}
```

My Animal class with its subclasses Lion, Rat, etc are defined in Animal.java

```
public class Animal {
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }   

}

class Rat extends Animal {}
class Lion extends Animal {}
```

Since I am getting the errors, I am guessing that the approach I am following may not be correct. In that case, is there any standard way of implementing this scenario in Java generics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `LionCage` class doesn't have to be generic, but it has to pass a concrete type paramter (`Lion`) in the `extends` clause:

```
public class LionCage extends Cage<Lion> {
    @Override
    public void add(Lion l) {
        cage.add(l);

    }
}
```